# Fluent NHibernate API documentation

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, documentation

My biggest obstacle to getting the hang of Fluent NHibernate so far has been finding the namespaces for the classes that I need to work through samples I find (blog posts, SO questions, etc.). I have looked around for a CHM or MSDN-like site that would make it easier to find things, but I have come up empty. I can find NHibernate API docs, but not Fluent NHibernate API docs.

Can anyone either confirm that I need to generate my own after building the source or point me to somewhere I have missed?

I have been using Reflector to find things and it works, but it is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would advice to use some kind of IDE which is capable of autoresolve the namespaces (Visual Studio, Sharpdevelop, ...) then you only need to copy paste the samples and use that.

useful resources

- [Getting Started](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started)
- [Example project showing Automapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/master/src/Examples.FirstAutomappedProject)

abstract

```
namespace    | used for
-----------------------
.Cfg         | fluently configuring the NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration object
.Mapping     | contains classes used to create Fluent Mappings
.Automapping | all you need to automaticly create mappings for classes
.Conventions | Interfaces to define Conventions used for Auto and Fluent mappings
```

Comment: How could I have possibly used VS as long as I have and never noticed its namespace resolution support? Thanks!